# Sessions using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a website where I process signatures. I transfer them to a png and save them to my server using AJAX. I'm trying to save them in a folder with the username of them user using a variable in PHP. I would like to have this variable stored in the session however when I tried it did not work.

I have tried having the session running in both pages

The beginning of the file with the sig pad:

```php
session_start();
$name = $_POST['name'];
$emp = $_POST['empid'];
$_SESSION["name"] = $name;
```

The submit function:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#signArea').signaturePad({drawOnly:true, drawBezierCurves:true, lineTop:90});
        });

        $("#btnSaveSign").click(function(e){
            html2canvas([document.getElementById('sign-pad')], {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var canvas_img_data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    var img_data = canvas_img_data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
                    //ajax call to save image inside folder
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'save_sign.php',
                        data: { img_data:img_data },
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (response) {
                           window.location.reload();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

```php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    $name = $_SESSION['name'];
    $result = array();
    $imagedata = base64_decode($_POST['img_data']);
    $filename = 'signature';
    //Location to where you want to created sign image
    $file_name = './contracts'.$name.'/'.$filename.'.png';
    file_put_contents($file_name,$imagedata);
    $result['status'] = 1;
    $result['file_name'] = $file_name;
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```